# Extract first word from a column and insert into existing column

Tags: r, text-extraction

I have a tibble and want to extract the first word from a column based on N/A criteria and insert it into an existin column the code I have is not working can anyone assist:

Column two has states names some rows are N/A's. What I want to do is If the row in column two is N/A then take the first word from column 7 to replace the N/A.

This is the code I currently have but I currently get an error.

```
for (i in which(is.na(PRC[,2]))){
PRC[int(i/11),2] <- substr(PRC[int(i/11),7],6) # needs to create a substring to pull the first word from source column to the state column and replace unknown
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(head(PRC))`

Answer (score 0):

Using several packages of the `tidyverse` you can easily obtain the desired result. I added an example df to show the solution. In the following code, you can use `mutate`, `across` and `ifelse` to substitute the entries with NA in the second column with the first word of the first column (using `str_extract` and regular expressions).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(fill = c("First state", "Second state", "Third state", "Fourth state", "Fifth state"),
             states = c("State B", "State A", NA, "State C", NA))

df |>
  mutate(across(states, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 
                                str_extract(fill, "^[A-z]+(?= )"), 
                                .x)))

# A tibble: 5 × 2
#  fill         states 
#  <chr>        <chr>  
#1 First state  State B
#2 Second state State A
#3 Third state  Third  
#4 Fourth state State C
#5 Fifth state  Fifth
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however, when I try this with my dataset I get the following error:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Columns `Minnesota`, `North Carolina`, `Massachusetts`, `Arizona`, `Tennessee`, etc. don't exist.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::mutate(...)
 2. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
 3. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
 5. dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
 6. dplyr:::expand_across(dot)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use `coalesce`:

```
df %>%
   mutate(states=coalesce(states, str_extract(fill, "\\w+")))

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  fill         states 
  <chr>        <chr>  
1 First state  State B
2 Second state State A
3 Third state  Third  
4 Fourth state State C
5 Fifth state  Fifth
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your assistance, I tried your code but I get the following error: "Error unexpected '=' in State="